# How do I parse my json for jquery ui autocomplete

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui

The json is returned from  a dynamic php function and looks like

```
 [{"tagid":"1","name":"scandalous"},{"tagid":"2","name":"crime"},{"tagid":"3","name":"entertainment"},{"tagid":"4","name":"finance"}]
```

The text input should use the name field.
The autocomplete is called as

```
$(document).on("focus", "#tagfilter", function(event) {
$(this).autocomplete({
source:  "/app/processes/tags.php?f=get_json_tags"
});

});
```

But I can't get the autocomplete to work

Cheers for any asistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery `map` to translate your starting item array or object to new array of items, than you can apply the input filter using `grep`.

The current filter is stored in the `request`, `source` function parameter.

Code:

```
$(this).autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term);
        var matcher = new RegExp("^" + re, "i");
        $.getJSON("/app/processes/tags.php?f=get_json_tags", function (data) {
            response($.grep(($.map(data, function (v, i) {
                return {
                    label: v.name,
                    value: v.name
                };
            })), function (item) {
                return matcher.test(item.value);
            }))
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: how is the url passed to that?

Comment: Thanks irvin that got me going :-)

Comment: @BarryHamilton glad to help you out. Do you need more info?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this example for [json remote datasource](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp):

Your code should therefore be:

```
$(this).autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "/app/processes/tags.php?f=get_json_tags",
          dataType: "jsonp",
          data: {
            q: request.term
          },
          success: function( data ) {
            response( $.map(data, function(v,i) { 
                    return { label: v.name, value:v.name }; 
                 }) 
            );
          }
        });
      }//[,
      //other: "options",
      //may: "be included",
      //right: "here" ]
});
```

Comment: that doesn't really answer the question I have already tested that solution but am unsure where I put mapping to transform my returned response into one that works with autocomplet.

Comment: I was still working on it. The parameter to response has to be mapped correctly using `$.map()`. Check out the update.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to have return the value from 2 different fields?

For example, right now the example only returns "v.name". Is there a way to allow the autocomplete to be more generic and also return "v.age" if someone types a matching age in?

I'm not sure how to return the value it finds.

```
return { label: v.name, value:v.name }; 
return { label: v.age, value:v.age };
```